# C program crash inverse file txt

Tags: c

I'm creating a program in C. I want this program to invert a txt file, avec geojson coordinates.

The program is running good, but when the txt file is too long, the programe crash....!
I think there is a problem with the memory but i don't find how to solucionate it.

Thanks in advance !

There my main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pile.h"
#include "pile_function.h"

#define TAILLE_MAX 5000 // Tableau de taille 1000




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE* fichier = NULL;
FILE* fichier_creer = NULL;
char chaine[TAILLE_MAX] = ""; // Chaîne vide de taille TAILLE_MAX
char concat[TAILLE_MAX] = "";
char final[TAILLE_MAX] = "";
const char s[2] = "]";

 char *token = malloc(sizeof(*token));
 Pile *tas;

 if ((tas = (Pile *) malloc (sizeof (Pile))) == NULL)
     return -1;
 initialisation (tas);


    fichier = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if (fichier != NULL)

       {

           // On peut lire et écrire dans le fichier
        printf("Ouverture du fichier\n");

         fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, fichier);

         fichier_creer = fopen("Fichier_Inverser.txt", "a+");
         if (fichier != NULL)
             {
             printf("Ouverture du fichier_creer\n");



               /* get the first token */
               token = strtok(chaine, s);

               /* walk through other tokens */
               while( token != NULL )
               {

                  strcpy(concat, token);
                  strcat(concat, s);


                  empiler(tas, concat);
                  token = strtok(NULL, s);
                  memset (concat, 0, sizeof (concat));
               }


                  while( tas->taille != 0 )
                  {

                      strcpy (final, depiler(tas));
                      fputs(final, fichier_creer);
                  }

              printf("\nFichier mise a jour\n");
             fclose(fichier_creer);
             printf("\nFermeture du fichier du fichier_creer\n");
             }





         else

           {
             printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier_creer");
           }

         fclose(fichier);
         printf("Fermeture du fichier du fichier\n");

       }

       else

       {
           printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier");

       }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There is my pile.h :

```
typedef struct ElementListe{
char *donnee;
struct ElementListe *suivant;
 } Element;

typedef struct ListeRepere{
Element *debut;
int taille;
} Pile;


/* initialisation */
void initialisation (Pile *tas);

/* EMPILER*/
int empiler (Pile *tas, char *donnee);

/* DEPILER*/
char *depiler (Pile *tas);

/* Affichage de élément en haut de la pile (LastInFirstOut) */
#define pile_donnee(tas)  tas->debut->donnee

/* Affiche la pile */
void affiche (Pile *tas);
```

There is my pile_function.h:

```
void initialisation (Pile * tas){
tas->debut = NULL;
tas->taille = 0;
}


int empiler (Pile * tas, char *donnee){
Element *nouveau_element;
 if ((nouveau_element = (Element *) malloc (sizeof (Element))) == NULL)
   return -1;
 if ((nouveau_element->donnee = (char *) malloc (50 * sizeof (char))) == NULL)
   return -1;
 strcpy (nouveau_element->donnee, donnee);
 nouveau_element->suivant = tas->debut;
 tas->debut = nouveau_element;
 tas->taille++;
}

char *depiler(Pile *pile)
{
 if (pile == NULL)
  {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
char *chaine =  malloc(sizeof(*chaine));
Element *elementDepile = pile->debut;

if (pile != NULL && pile->debut != NULL)
 {
    strcpy (chaine, elementDepile->donnee);
    pile->debut = elementDepile->suivant;
    free(elementDepile);
 }
pile->taille--;

return chaine;
}


void affiche (Pile * tas){
 Element *courant;
 int i;
 courant = tas->debut;

 for(i=0;i<tas->taille;++i){
   printf("%s\n", courant->donnee);
   courant = courant->suivant;
 }
}
```

There is for exemple a list of coordinate, it doesn't work :

```
[2.2528324,49.0413749],[2.2530099,49.0409694],[2.2529714,49.0409477],[2.2529531,49.040845],[2.2528231,49.040697],[2.2525572,49.0405152],[2.2521051,49.0402405],[2.2518017,49.0400133],[2.2515308,49.0397237],[2.2514333,49.0395455],[2.2514103,49.0394521],[2.2514134,49.0393256],[2.25172,49.0383752],[2.2517745,49.0380228],[2.2518929,49.0377766],[2.2520333,49.0375694],[2.2522566,49.0373093],[2.2523922,49.0372076],[2.2525084,49.036936],[2.2528797,49.0363597],[2.2529077,49.0362346],[2.2528555,49.0359416],[2.2527984,49.0358494],[2.2527631,49.0358471],[2.2494004,49.0368099],[2.2445056,49.0382113],[2.2438535,49.0351289],[2.2434025,49.0334159],[2.2433668,49.0333207],[2.2424539,49.0292753],[2.242455,49.0290301],[2.2425994,49.0285152],[2.2425996,49.0284322],[2.241938,49.0267597],[2.241008,49.0254301],[2.2405995,49.0251103],[2.2405338,49.0250148],[2.2404128,49.0247205],[2.2403438,49.0244781],[2.2403436,49.0243775],[2.239998,49.0235028],[2.2399302,49.0233991],[2.2398091,49.0233274],[2.2397032,49.0232808],[2.2395594,49.0232176],[2.2394263,49.0231172],[2.2393327,49.0230396],[2.2392098,49.0229535],[2.2387176,49.0225323],[2.238216,49.0221354],[2.237813,49.0218217],[2.2375089,49.0214585],[2.2373633,49.0215158],[2.2371741,49.0213435],[2.2364466,49.0204618],[2.2363631,49.0202973],[2.2359734,49.0197239],[2.2358766,49.0195764],[2.23573,49.0192646],[2.2356873,49.0192694],[2.235498,49.0189371],[2.2354933,49.0189123],[2.2352065,49.0184121],[2.23519,49.0184137],[2.2350145,49.0184304],[2.2348705,49.0184441],[2.2342795,49.0177464],[2.2340851,49.017802],[2.2338829,49.0175392],[2.2338473,49.017546],[2.2331775,49.0168764],[2.2327003,49.0163514],[2.2326684,49.0163499],[2.231627,49.0154023],[2.2312705,49.0150763],[2.2311292,49.0149744],[2.2302659,49.0144945],[2.2301856,49.0144539]
```

But with the same list but short , it works :

```
[2.2528324,49.0413749],[2.2530099,49.0409694],[2.2529714,49.0409477],[2.2529531,49.040845],[2.2528231,49.040697],[2.2525572,49.0405152],[2.2521051,49.0402405],[2.2518017,49.0400133],[2.2515308,49.0397237],[2.2514333,49.0395455],[2.2514103,49.0394521],[2.2514134,49.0393256],[2.25172,49.0383752],[2.2517745,49.0380228],[2.2518929,49.0377766],[2.2520333,49.0375694],[2.2522566,49.0373093],[2.2523922,49.0372076],[2.2525084,49.036936],[2.2528797,49.0363597]
```

I'm a begineer..so maybe i'm not doing it good.
Thanks you for your reply.

Jordan

Comment: And it crashes on which line? What does debugging show you?

Comment: I don't know how to debug it....i'm running the program directly on the terminal....

Comment: Hawking's law as applied to collaborative programming: each non-English identifier cuts your potential audeince in half.

Comment: "I don't know how to debug it". A good time to learn it is now.

Comment: @JordanMatas If you're running Linux, you probably need to use [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger). For OS X, use [lldb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)).

Comment: `char *chaine =  malloc(sizeof(*chaine));` => Here `sizeof(*chaine) == 1` because type is `char *` so pointed type is `char` and `sizeof(char) == 1`. You probably want `char *chaine = (char *) malloc(strlen(elementDepile->donnee) * sizeof(char));`

Comment: @Fefux Cool !! That resolve the problem....! +1

I'm going to look you're answer carefully. I understand my mistake, but i don't understand yet why you do  strlen(elementDepile->donnee) * sizeof(char)

But thanks !

Comment: add exit(1); to your code to stop it. Put in lots of printf(), if you don't want to learn gdb. This is also debugging and very useful.

Comment: It's because malloc allocates memory in number of byte. Here, `sizeof(char) == 1` so no problem if you forget it. But if you want `strlen(elementDepile->donnee)` type of `int`, you have to write `malloc(strlen(elementDepile->donnee) * sizeof(int))` because `int` size is 4 bytes

Comment: @Fefux Oh yeah ! Okay, that was easy :-P
So it depend of what type is "donnee" ....
Thank you!

Comment: Arf, be carefull `donnee` is type of `char *` which size is 4 on 32bit system and 8 on 64bit (this is a pointer). It depends more of what kind of type you want (here `donnee` is `char *` so you want to store a `string` and each element of a C string is type of `char`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *chaine =  malloc(sizeof(*chaine));` => Here `sizeof(*chaine) == 1` because type is `char *` so pointed type is `char` and `sizeof(char) == 1`. You probably want `char *chaine = (char *) malloc(strlen(elementDepile->donnee) * sizeof(char));`
 – Fefux